# same post displaying in every title and post

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

hello everyone i am just wondering why my Viewpost.php 
is displaying the same post for each title for the same user? 
i have try looking up why _GET displays the same post 
now i am lost so if any one knows why it is displaying the same post for the same user each post that be great

PS i know i should make a back up every time i do something like this

now i know that :(

the code

```html
<?php
     $page = $_GET['page'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` LEFT JOIN `admin` ON admin.id = news.username WHERE admin.id = '$page' LIMIT 1";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
     if( $result )    
     while($blog = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    ?>       
          <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">           
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $blog["title"]; ?></h2>
              <?php  
              echo '</br>';
            if ($blog['sponored'] === "SPONSORED") {
echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success  pull-right"><sponored>'. $blog['sponored'] .'</sponored></span>';  
      } else {
echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info pull-right"><post>' . $blog['sponored'] . '</post></span>';
 } 
?>                               
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div> </br>

<?php echo $blog["content"]; ?>
              <p class="card-text">
              </p>                       
            </div>            
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge pull-left"><light-css>author </light-css>
    <a href='/<?php echo $blog["id"]; ?>/<?php echo $blog["username"]; ?>.php'><user-css><?php echo $blog["username"]; ?></user-css></a>   
</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge pull-right"><light-css>Time</light-css><admin-css><?php echo date('h:i A' , strtotime($blog['Published']));?></admin-css></span>                          
 <span class="badge badge-pill badge pull-right"><light-css>on</light-css><admin-css><?php echo date('l jS F Y' , strtotime($blog['Published']));?></admin-css></span>                          
                       
 <div id='disqus_thread'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
          var disqus_shortname = '<?php echo $row["disqus"]; ?>'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
              (function() {
              var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
              dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
              (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
          })();
        </script>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>           
            <a href="<?php echo $row['siteurl']; ?>">home</a>
            </br>
        </div>       
       <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What do the news and admin tables look like? Also your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. You may want to look into sanitizing your inputs for your sites safety.

Comment: You have `LIMIT 1` in the query, so it just selects one post.

Comment: yes i know i have LIMIT 1  thats to display the 1 post so it dont show all of them unless thats wrong  i dont know barmar

Comment: Jfed  here image off tables https://imgur.com/a/AV1de6Y

Comment: Is it possible you meant  where  news.id = '$page' instead of where admin.id = '$page'

Comment: Jfed i dont know i just dont get it why when i add the numbers from the database into the url it shows the right post its odd

Comment: If you want to show a different post each time, you need to put something in the query that selects the specific post that you want. Right now you just let it select 1 post to show, and there's nothing that changes which one it selects.

Comment: barmar ok how would i do that coz  the database numbers work just when you click the title it dont show that post for that title link